# How can you Iterate through vector and extract smallest value on each iteration

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I have a vector of size four and want to be able to iterate through it extract the smallest value on each iteration and assign it to a variable.

```
vector <double> vs;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;


vs.push_back(1); vs.push_back(2); vs.push_back(3); vs.push_back(4);
```

and I want a= 1, b=2, c=3, d=4. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: sort the vector and then just assign in order? Or don't I understand what you're asking?

Comment: In case it's a homework, put ' homework ' tag in it. People will (should) try to give you a hint as to how to solve the problem rather then just typing the answer for you. If it's not a homework, disregard dis comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to sort the `vector` (using `std::sort`) - or a copy of the vector if you need to preserve the original vector - and assign `a = vs[0]`, `b = vs[1]`, etc.